# Getting Syntax error in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var hdata = '<select id="drpTransProvider" style="width:150px;" onchange="return SetValueofDropdown(\"transprovider\",this.value);"><option value=""></option>';
```

why there is an syntax error in browser ?

it is like

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

return SetValueofDropdown(
```

Comment: What are you doing with this variable?

Comment: Would be great if you can give complete code and what you are trying to do.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape `'` not `"`, so :

```
var hdata = '<select id="drpTransProvider" style="width:150px;"
onchange="return SetValueofDropdown(\'transprovider\',this.value);"><option value=""></option>';
```

Comment: Same answer as me but I have posted before you

Comment: @AmitAgrawal So what? You were 13 seconds faster, and this has marginally more explanation as to what has been changed. If you want upvotes, consider slightly more supporting text than "Try this".

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var hdata = '<select id="drpTransProvider" style="width:150px;" 
onchange="return SetValueofDropdown(\'transprovider\',this.value);"><option value=""> </option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using " characters inside your onclick attribute that is declared using " characters too. Try this:

```
onchange="return SetValueofDropdown(\'transprovider\',this.value);"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code but I didn't get any error.I added extra code that is  at last.
I used in this manner.

My Html Code:

```
<span id="test"></span>
```

My script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var hdata = '<select id="drpTransProvider" style="width:150px;" onchange="return SetValueofDropdown(\"transprovider\",this.value);"><option value=""></option></select>';
            $('#test').html(hdata);
        });
</script>
```